# Getting a repeated substring pattern from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a list of files in a folder with the names like "C123 fileName.jpg" or "D456 6G fileName.jpg". I want to extract seperately the Number followed by characters in the file, such as "C123" "D456" "6G". How can I achieve this? There can be many of this Number_FollowedByLetter patterns in the string. If I can get those associated to the Original file Name it would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `filename.Split(" ");` will start you off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method that will help you out is `String.Split()`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

You can seperate your complete filename into different parts by using a specific seperate-letter or -string. Further search for the keyword on google and SO recommended :)